# Python unable to read my csv due to extra carriage returns

Tags: python, http-status-code-404

Sorry if this is redundant but I've tried very hard to look for the answer to this but I've been unable to find one. I'm very new to this so please bear with me:

My objective is for a piece of code to read through a csv full of urls, and return a http status code. I have Python 2.7.5. The outcome of each row would give me the url and the status code, something like this: www.stackoverflow.com: 200.

My csv is a single column csv full of hundreds of urls, one per row. The code I am using is below and when I run this code, it gives me a /r separating two urls similar to this:

{http://www.stackoverflow.com/test\rhttp://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/': 404}

What I would like to see is the two urls separated, and each with their own http status code:

{'http://www.stackoverflow.com': 200, 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/': 404}

But there seems to be an extra \r when Python reads the csv, so it doesn't read the urls correctly. I know folks have said that strip() isn't an all inclusive wiper-outer so any advice on what to do to make this work, would be very much appreciated.

```
import requests
def get_url_status(url):
    try:
       r = requests.head(url)
       return url, r.status_code
    except requests.ConnectionError:
       print "failed to connect"
       return url, 'error'


results = {}
with open('url2.csv', 'rb') as infile:
   for url in infile:
       url = url.strip() # "http://datafox.co"
       url_status = get_url_status(url)
       results[url_status[0]] = url_status[1]
   print results
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with csv format, but it would certainly help if you show us a sample of the actual text file you are trying to read.

Comment: If you are reading from a CSV file, consider using python's csv module, which will correctly treat the \r as a new line character. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the comments. I've figured out the problem - next time I'll be sure to include a sample of the actual file I'm referring to. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to figure out how your csv file is formatted, before feeding it to Python.

First, make sure it has consistent line endings.  If it has newlines sometimes, and crlf others, that's probably a problem that needs to be corrected.

If you're on a *ix system, tr might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for that clue. You were right, once I saved the file in a different format, it worked ok. Thanks again for your time.